# Django simple history inheritance getting from parent to child history

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-simple-history

I am trying to use [django-simple-history](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for keeping state of an Object.

Let's say i have the following:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    fields...
    history = HistoricalRecords(inherit=True)

class Child(Parent):
    fields...

class Invoice(models.Model):
    fields...
    parent_history = models.ForeignKey("app.HistoricalParent", blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT, help_text="This keeps the state of the Child when Invoice is generated")
    parent =  models.ForeignKey(Parent, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT) # can be removed so foreign key loop gets eliminated
```

How can i reach from `Invoice` to `Child`?

```
Invoice.objects.get(id=1).parent_history.child
```

Does not work and raise

```
AttributeError: 'HistoricalParent' object has no attribute 'child'
```

and this is how i am reaching `Child` from `Parent`

```
Invoice.objects.get(id=1).parent.child
```

I can't find the foreign key from `HistoricalChild` to `HistoricalParent`. Am i missing something? Does django-simple-history works some other way?

Comment: What is the definition of the `HistoricalParent` class?

Comment: @KrazyMax It is defined by `django-simple-history` it's basically same as `Parent` plus couple of more columns like `change_reason, history_id, history_date and histtory_type`

Comment: Ok. Something I do not understand, is your `Child` class. Do you want it to inheritate from the `Parent` class? Like to have the same fields as your `Parent` class? Something is not clear in the names you gave. Reading you, it sounds normal that you can not access `child` from `invoice` because `parent_history` does not have a `child` field (is there a confuse on your side between `parent_history` and `Parent`?

Comment: @KrazyMax well `django` model inheritance keeps a foreign key from `Child` to `Parent` and so i have reverse foreign key from `Parent` to `Child`. I would have expected the same from `django-simple-history` but apparently `HistoricalChild` keeps the same foreign key to `Parent` instead of `HistoricalParent`

Comment: actually that's where you are wrong: there is not any `ForeignKey` created automatically between a parent and its child when the child inherits from the parent. You have to explicitely define a relationship for that. Also, if you want 2 classes to have common attributes and methods, I would suggest to create an abstract model (a mixin), then to make your `Parent` and `Child` to inheritate from that mixin. If that sounds like a good idea to you, I can edit my answer to show you an example!

Comment: Woops looks like I'm wrong and that a `one-to-one` field might be defined by default actually. Will investigate that for my own sake.

Comment: Yeap sorry that's here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance, it is just something I never use actually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So let me break the foreign key relation when using `django-simple-history`

So the `HistoricalChild` dosn't get a foreign key to `HistoricalParent`

```
HistoricalChild = apps.get_model('app', 'HistoricalChild')
HistoricalChild.objects.filter(parent_ptr_id=invoice.parent_history.id).order_by('-history_date')
```

Will return so many item and it's pretty useless to me cause the parent has it's state from a certain date but the child is from the future

and this mean i can't recreate a full child at by having a reference to it's historical parent at certain point in time..

i ended up using `historical_date` for recreating a `Child` instance from certain time, like so

```
parent_dict = apps.get_model('order', 'HistoricalParent').objects.filter(history_date__lte=invoice.created_date).order_by('-history_date').values().first()
child_dict = apps.get_model('app', 'HistoricalChild').objects.filter(history_date__lte=invoice.created_date).order_by('-history_date').values().first()

child_dict.update(parent_dict)

for field in ['history_change_reason', 'history_id', 'history_type', 'history_date', 'history_user_id']:
    child_dict.pop(field)

child_from_the_past = Child(**child_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty clear to me: there is no `child` attribute associate to your `Parent` model. You can not access `child` from `parent` as there is no relation (from a database point of view) between both of them. To inherit from a parent class does not imply any relationship between them, only that the child will inheritate from parent's attributes and methods, that's all.

I'm not sure this is what you want to do, but it is possible to access an object parent through reverse relationships.

For instance, if you have a clear link between `Parent` and `Child` like the following:

```py
class Parent(models.Model):
    fields...
    history = HistoricalRecords(inherit=True)

class Child(models.Model):
    fields...
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='blabla')
```

then, `parent` can be access as follows: `child.parent` (no surprise), but child can also be accessed from `parent` thanks to the inverse relationship (check the `related_name` parameter): `parent.blabla`.

Hope that helps!